# POST json file using request module

Tags: json, node.js, curl, npm-request

I am planning to translate the `curl` **API call** below to `node.js` though I am still getting an `error` when doing a **POST**.

```
curl  -X POST --user user1@customer1:secret http://demo.test.com/controller/actions/38 -F file=@ExportActions.json
```

Below is initial code using the request - npm module, but the API call still fails.

```
var requestdata = fs.readFileSync('./ExportActions.json').toString();

var request = require('request');
request.post({
     url: 'https://demo.test.com/controller/actions/38',
     auth: {
        'user': 'user1@customer1',
        'pass': 'secret'
    },
    body: requestdata
}, function(error, response, body){
   console.log(body);
});
```

I am getting the error below every time I run the script:

```
Could not import Actions: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Are there any **workarounds** when **posting** a **JSON** file using the `npm request` module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to upload to file by posting it to the body. It looks like the server wants a multi-part upload instead. This might work better

```
var req = require('request');
request.post({
   url: 'https://demo.test.com/controller/actions/38',
   auth: {
      'user': 'user1@customer1',
      'pass': 'secret'
  },
}, function(error, response, body){
     console.log(body);
});

var form = req.form()
form.append('file', fs.readFileSync('./ExportActions.json'));
```

Comment: `body` is `undefined`. Is that correct? The `API` call still failed though.

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't post things before coffee. No you don't need to send the body - I meant to remove that. I edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Postman client to check this api instead of curl.